# Each li different action

Tags: jquery, slider, margin

I'm trying to build my own little (full page jquery slider) and I'm trying to figure out how to do the navigation but I don't seem to be able to fix it.

I have a variable that stores the current width of the window and resizes it if that's needed.

```
var lastWidth   = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width()!=lastWidth){

        //execute code.
    }
});
```

My navigation is a simple list of 3 items.

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>

<div id="pageslider">
    <div id="home">Home content</div>
    <div id="portfolio">Portfolio content</div>
    <div id="blog">Blog content</div>
    <div id="contact">Contact content</div>
<div>
```

This is the code that gives the right value to my #sliderpage

```
$("#pageslider").css({"min-width": (lastWidth * 4)});
```

So my idea is this, I make a variable in which I store the lastWidth * 1 , * 2 , * 3.

```
var scrollWidth = [(-lastWidth * 1),-lastWidth * 2,-lastWidth * 3]
```

Then if I can link the first li with the first value in that variable I have the right amount of margin needed.

But obviously I can't figure out how to do that, and this feels really convoluted

Currently I use this code as my click function:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $('li').each(function(i) {
        $('body').find('#pageslider').animate({
        "margin-left":scrollWidth[i]},1800,
        'easeInOutQuint');
    });
});
```

This obviously does not work, it does react to the click but it does not care on what LI. Also it runs all the values from scrollWidth.

**Here is a small jsFiddle of my current set up : http://jsfiddle.net/L29pq/49/**

Comment: you mean run on `li`s and redefine their `margin`?

Comment: I mean, the first LI should get the first value in the scrollWidth variable, the second LI should get the second value and so on.

Comment: oh , i see your update

Answer (score 1):

If you always want the first list item to refer to the second width of the slider, you can reference the index as a multiplier:

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
  $('#pageslider').animate({
    "margin-left":lastWidth*(1 + $('ul li').index($(this)))},1800,
    'easeInOutQuint');
});
```

This would become less ambiguous if you gave the ul element an id so you could use $('ul#listid li') instead of $('ul li')

Explanation:

```
#('ul#listid li')
```

selects all li objects that are children of the ul object with id listid, and returns them as a jQuery object.

This object has an index function that is very similar to the javascript Array.indexOf function.  The call

```
#('ul#listid li').index($(this))
```

within the click handler will return the zero-based index of the li that was clicked ($(this)) within the object returned by the selector.

Add one to make the index one-based and multiply by the lastWidth to get the margin offset that you need.

Comment: This works excellent! Just what I wanted. But I don't really understand why it works. Which is a bit of the point of this excercise ;).

the click function multiplies the lastWidth by 1 standard. But how does this part work?

     $('ul li').index($(this))

Answer (score 0):

I would just give an id to your li elements and then use it to decide.

```
<li id="link1"><a href="" class="portfolio">portfolio</a>
</li>
<li id="link2"><a href="">blogs</a>
</li>
<li id="link3"><a href="">contact</a>
</li>

$('li').click(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr("id");
    num = num.charAt(num.length-1);
    $('body').find('#pageslider').animate({
    "margin-left":scrollWidth[num]},1800);
});
```

Here is a fiddle of it, though I don't think it works very good because of window width in the fiddle.  You can see that it is moving how it should though.  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esGPc/)